# Reverse arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I reverse arrays from this order:

```
Array
(
    [message] => Text 2
    [time] => 16:00:00
)
Array
(
    [message] => Text 1
    [time] => 15:00:00
)
```

To order:

```
Array
(
    [message] => Text 1
    [time] => 15:00:00
)
Array
(
    [message] => Text 2
    [time] => 16:00:00
)
```

I am building a chat script with php and mysql and I would just like to reverse this. So that new messages begin at the bottom. Like:

```
15:00 > Text 1
16:00 > Text 2
17:00 > Text 3
18:00 > Text 4
19:00 > Text 5
<input type='text'><submit>
```

How can I do this? array_reverse() and rsort() does not work in thiscase.

**EDIT:**

I am currently using:

```
$results = $conn->query("SELECT message, datetime FROM chats ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    print "</pre>";

    //echo '<div class="text">'.$row["message"].'</div>';
    //echo '<div class="time">'.$row["datetime"].'</div>';
}

output:

Array
(
    [message] => text 3
    [datetime] => 2016-08-29 18:11:30
)
Array
(
    [message] => text 2
    [datetime] => 2016-08-29 18:11:29
)
Array
(
    [message] => text 1
    [datetime] => 2016-08-29 18:11:27
)
```

Comment: This seems to be the output of a loop?

Comment: Why not fetch them in the correct order? `SELECT ... ORDER BY id DESC`?

Comment: you can try as created date descending order

Comment: `array_reverse` does work in _this_ case, maybe not the real case.

Comment: @tadman I am already doing this, see edit.

Comment: @bretterer Thanks! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a few ways, however if you're using a for() loop to print out the messages for your chat, it would probably be the easiest to just run the for() loop counting backwards.

## Using for()

If you start a counter loop with an initial value of the array's element count subtract one, you can print each element in the array in reverse order, for example;

```
<?php
    /* You can replace this with the method you need for your program using SQL, I just used a static array as an example */

    $messages = array(
        array("message" => "Text 5", "time" => "19:00"),
        array("message" => "Text 4", "time" => "18:00"),
        array("message" => "Text 3", "time" => "17:00"),
        array("message" => "Text 2", "time" => "16:00"),
        array("message" => "Text 1", "time" => "15:00"),
    );

    // This can be used where you're outputting the chat messages
    for($i = (count($messages) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        echo $messages[$i]["time"] . ": " . $messages[$i]["message"] . "<br />";
    }
```

And this gives the output that you want;

```
15:00: Text 1
16:00: Text 2
17:00: Text 3
18:00: Text 4
19:00: Text 5
```

## Using MySQL "DESC"

You can also just fetch the items in descending order via MySQL as pointed out by tadman, using the query he provided. If you want to limit how large your chat gets by omitting older messages, you can also set a limit in the query like this (for the example, it's limited to 5 messages);

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Edit:** I didn't see that you used the second answer until after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sort something coming out of the database with php, just sort it with your query

```
//ORDER BY datetime ASC

$results = $conn->query("SELECT message, datetime FROM chats ORDER BY datetime ASC LIMIT 3");
```

ORDER BY field ASC -> means sort by field ascending
ORDER BY field DESC -> means sort by field descending

MYSQL Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html